# Dua Prophet Mohammad PBUH recite when offered food

Tags: dua

I heard a specific Dua Prophet PBUH recite when someone offer him food. I need that with translation in URDU or ENGLISH.

Comment: W Salam, Yes after the meal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is an overload of information but I think it is helpful.
I will only quote dua's and supplications which have some strong reference in the sunnah.

Dua' if one ends his meal:

> ‘All praise is due to Allah who fed me this and granted it as provision to me, without any effort from me nor power (Jami' [at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/48/89))

Dua' if somebody is feeding you or giving you to drink or you wanted to drink:

> Allah, feed him who fed me and give drink to him who provided me drink. (sahih [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/36/236))

Dua' for the hosts who offered a meal:

> O Allah. bless them in what You have provided them as a sustenance; and forgive them and have mercy upon them. (sahih [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/36/202))

or

> “All praise is due to Allah, abundant, good, blessed praise, without being left off, nor being without need of it, O our Lord (sahih [al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/70/87))

In case you have been invited to break your fast you can make this dua' for your hosts:

> May the fasting (men) break their fast with you, and the pious eat your food, and the angels pray for blessing on you. (Sunan [abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/28/119))